# Vectors using two point values crash on Android 5.0.1 and 5.0.2?

Tags: android, vector, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm using some of the Vectors from Android Download site [here](https://www.google.com/design/icons/index.html).

Icons like the [contact phone icon](https://www.google.com/design/icons/index.html#ic_contact_phone).

And putting it into a file as described here:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/grey"
        android:pathData="M22 3H2C.9 3 0 3.9 0 5v14c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h20c1.1 0 1.99-.9 1.99-2L24 5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zM8 6c1.66 0 3 1.34 3 3s-1.34 3-3 3-3-1.34-3-3 1.34-3 3-3zm6 12H2v-1c0-2 4-3.1 6-3.1s6 1.1 6 3.1v1zm3.85-4h1.64L21 16l-1.99 1.99c-1.31-.98-2.28-2.38-2.73-3.99-.18-.64-.28-1.31-.28-2s.1-1.36.28-2c.45-1.62 1.42-3.01 2.73-3.99L21 8l-1.51 2h-1.64c-.22.63-.35 1.3-.35 2s.13 1.37.35 2z"/>

</vector>
```

The problem is on Samsung S4 and HTC One (5.0.1 and 5.0.2)

```
11-05 13:37:34.380 uk.co.test.test W/System.err: Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-xxhdpi-v21/ic_grey_dark_absence_24dp.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020071
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3735)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3603)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1852)
    at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:408)
    at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(ContextCompatApi21.java:26)
    at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:321)
    at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:177)
    at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:170)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:53)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:74)
    at uk.co.test.test.view.MenuItemView.init(MenuItemView.java:42)
    at uk.co.test.test.view.MenuItemView.<init>(MenuItemView.java:22)
11-05 13:37:34.380 uk.co.test.test W/System.err:    ... 32 more
11-05 13:37:34.380 uk.co.test.test W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: "1.1.9"
    at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
    at java.lang.StringToReal.initialParse(StringToReal.java:160)
    at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:323)
    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:306)
    at android.util.PathParser.getFloats(PathParser.java:178)
    at android.util.PathParser.createNodesFromPathData(PathParser.java:59)
    at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VFullPath.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawable.java:1439)
    at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VFullPath.inflate(VectorDrawable.java:1421)
    at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.inflateInternal(VectorDrawable.java:542)
    at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.inflate(VectorDrawable.java:458)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1150)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1063)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3719)
```

I've found however, that this is being caused by any vector with a value  containing two "."'s, such as 1.1.9. If you change the above vector to the basket icon:

```
<path
    android:fillColor="@color/grey"
    android:pathData="M17.21,9l-4.38,-6.56c-0.19,-0.28 -0.51,-0.42 -0.83,-0.42 -0.32,0 -0.64,0.14 -0.83,0.43L6.79,9H2c-0.55,0 -1,0.45 -1,1 0,0.09 0.01,0.18 0.04,0.27l2.54,9.27c0.23,0.84 1,1.46 1.92,1.46h13c0.92,0 1.69,-0.62 1.93,-1.46l2.54,-9.27L23,10c0,-0.55 -0.45,-1 -1,-1h-4.79zM9,9l3,-4.4L15,9H9zm3,8c-1.1,0 -2,-0.9 -2,-2s0.9,-2 2,-2 2,0.9 2,2 -0.9,2 -2,2z"/>
```

everything works fine.

I couldn't find a reported bug on code.google.com/p/android, I was wondering if there is a work around other than "change all your vectors" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same icons created in Vector Asset Studio don't seem to suffer from this problem. So I guess the solution is to always use Vector Asset Studio to create your vector `xml` files.

Comment: I can't believe this. The same thing happened to me.. And it was just for what you said. And yes, it was only happening on Samsung, they will get me crazy one day.

Comment: Exactly what happened to me. I was using svg files from generated using Google Icons and they were also giving this error. Now I stick to vectors from studio!